# MySQL replication not updating slave

Tags: mysql, replication

Trying to set up replication master - slave.

Master my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port = 3306
server-id = 1
log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
replicate-do-db = Test
```

Slave my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
log_output              = "FILE"
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
server-id = 2
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
replicate-do-db = Test
```

SHOW SLAVE STATUS shows

```
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

In relay log i see query executed on master.
And Read_Master_Log_Pos also updates. 
But in general_log_file appear only

```
130530 14:50:25   523 Query     BEGIN
                  523 Query     COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */
```

And changes on master not executed on slave. What i have missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be due to the following option:

`replicate-do-db = Test`

The [replicate-do-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table) option can be very tricky and can sometimes [behave in a manner that appears illogical](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/).

It will only replicate statements where the **default** ((that is, the one selected by USE) database is set. So in your example that would mean that this is replicated:

`use Test`;

`insert into myTable (column) values (value);`

But this will **not** be replicated:

`insert into Test.myTable (column) values (value);`

Try using the [replicate-wild-do-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table) option instead:

`replicate-wild-do-table=Test.%`

Hopefully you will get some joy.

Comment: Glad it did. Could you indicate as much my accepting the answer, please?